# Isekai manga where main character is an inventor but wants to be an adventurer

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I recently read an *isekai* manga where the MC invented some stuff but wanted to be an adventurer. I remembered he invented a hot bath system, paper, etc.

I think in the last chapter, he was asked where he got the ideas or something like that, and he just said "I just point out what I feel need to be better, the works are all being done by the workers" and he proceeded to say the most advance carriage he rode in sucks and hurt his butt even though it is the latest model, which made the noble/rich guy angry. Then he proceeded to tell his friends about how to improve the carriage, such as changing the leaf spring into helical spring.

What is the title of this manga?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Argate Online](https://myanimelist.net/manga/108164/Argate_Online)* comes to mind, I believe he is an inventor in the first chapters and then decides to become an adventurer.

> Izu Takashi was just playing the online game "Argate Online" as usual, but he suddenly noticed something strange, his level is now 1!? Also, he can not log out and the pain control function does not work anymore... It seems like he wandered into another world-like game that became a reality...

Here's him proposing a hot tub in chapter 7:

[image: Argate Online chapter 7 page showing the hot tub proposal]

Comment: yes this is the one thanks