# Isekai manga where the main character meets a girl who has dressed as a boy but is a girl

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character is transported into another world and he starts working as an adventurer to earn money. Some time later while he's doing a quest and saves a group of people from getting attacked and the person that was getting attack was a girl who has dressed as a boy to conceal her identity. She always has a stern look on her face.

When the main character has enough money to buy a house then he buys himself a bath (I think it was with a skill or he made it by hand or someone made it for him) then the butler came to see the bath and asked to have the same thing in their house because they also bought a house near the main character's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might it be *[Argate Online](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/argate-online)* as per [Isekai manga where main character is an inventor but wants to be an adventurer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207553/isekai-manga-where-main-character-is-an-inventor-but-wants-to-be-an-adventurer)?

> Izu Takashi was just playing the online game -Argate Online- like usual, but he suddenly noticed something strange, his level is now....!! Also he can not log out and the pain reduced function does not work.....

Chapter 7 has the bath.

[image: Argate Online chapter 7 page showing the hot tub proposal]

Comment: Thanks this is the one I was looking for

Comment: @Morili: Glad I could help. :) It was the mention of the bath that reminded me.